# How to deploy socket.io project so that it is served by the same web server as my create-react-app client

Tags: socket.io, create-react-app

I have an existing public-facing `create-react-app` -based client up and running, and I now want to incorporate `socket.io` for real-time communication between users.

From all examples and documentation, I see that the `socket.io` logic needs to be hosted in a separate `node.js` project.  <s>My question is, must this separate `node.js` project also be public-facing?  in other words, must the individual browsers connecting to my React client be able to communicate with the socket.io node.js project?</s>

EDIT:  After a better understanding (thanks @jonrsharpe), my question becomes, given the typical example of a React Client (created with create-react-app), and a separate node.js server (in the same repo), like one would find [here](https://medium.com/swlh/build-a-real-time-chat-app-with-react-hooks-and-socket-io-4859c9afecb0) or [here](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-react/), I'm really failing to understand how this translates into a production deployment?

Especially with @jonrsharpe alluding to the fact that the socket.io endpoints *can* be incorporated into the web server that is serving up my react app - how do I do that?

Comment: *"the individual browsers connecting to my React client"* - I'm not sure what you mean by this, the individual browsers are **running** the React client. Your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66549645/3001761) has the same misapprehension, perhaps you are confusing the dev server (which is a Node server, but which you shouldn't be using in prod) with the actual app?

Comment: Yeah perhaps I'm having a brain fart? In the examples, you typically have the socket.io server running on port x, and the react client running on port y.  But I'm failing to understand how this translates into a public-facing production deployment.  If the browser navigates to www.myapp.com, and this launches the React client in the browser, how does it connect to the server?  Must this be deployed, for example, to mysocketioserver.myapp.com?

Comment: The React client is *running* in the user's browser. What's running on your machine is likely just a vanilla web server to allow the user to download the build outputs (static HTML, JS, CSS, ...). That *can* be the same server that's exposing the WS endpoints, REST API, etc. (that's how [this starter kit](https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture) I put together works in prod mode, for example). You *can* run the WS endpoints on a different server and even a different domain, but then you need to tell the client where to find it.

Comment: But the short answer is yes - the socket.io endpoints need to be accessible, or the front-end app can't connect to them.